# qmake numeric variable comparation

Tags: qt, qmake, qt5

I've downloaded Qt 5 and tried to build my project. Projects are now required to add widgets to QT variable, but that produces a warning with older version:

> Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets

The simple solution seem to add a simple check:

```
equals( $$QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5 ) {
  message(" ================ QT 5 ================ ")
  QT += widgets
} else {
  message(" ================ QT 4 ================ ")
}
```

That did not worked (QT 4 is printed). It is true that equals is not part of the [qmake function reference](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-function-reference.html), but contains is. So tried with:

```
contains( $$QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5 )   {
  message(" ================ QT 5 ================ ")
  QT += widgets
} else {
  message(" ================ QT 4 ================ ")
}
```

but that did not worked, either. Various other combinations like contains( "$$QT_MAJOR_VERSION", "5" ) do not work.

The assumption that $$QT_MAJOR_VERSION is 4 or 5 is checked with a line like:

```
message( $$QT_MAJOR_VERSION )
```

Setting a local variable and testing for its value in this way does not work.

The conclusion to all this is that I don't understand something fundamental about qmake mechanism. So how does one compares a variable against a value in qmake .pro file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

Answer (score 5):

Besides what Zlatomir said, `greaterThan` is a strict comparison (not "greater and equal than"). You can also use `isEqual(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5)` to test for numerical equality.

Note that you should not specify `$$` for `QT_MAJOR_VERSION` , `QT_MINOR_VERSION` and `QT_PATCH_VERSION`.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that

```
equals (QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4)
{
   //some conditional stuff
}
```

does not work, but

```
equals (QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
   //some conditional stuff
}
```

works ... it is sensitive to the position of the opening brace! Wierd